# Чем отличается sleep от wait?

Tags: java, многопоточность, java-faq

Чем отличается `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);` от `this.wait(1000)`?

Comment: Например тем, что `sleep` мёртво ждёт, а `wait` может завершиться от `notify()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`wait` может быть "разбужен" другим потоком с использованием `notify`, `sleep` не может. Так же `wait` (и`notify`) должны в быть `synchronized`  блоке.

```
Object obj = ...;
synchronized (obj) {
    obj.wait();
}
```

Пока текущий (выполняющийся) поток - ожидает `waits` и `releases`, другой поток может сделать

```
synchronized (obj) { obj.notify(); }
```

(на том же `obj`) и первый поток проснётся.
Можно так же вызвать `notifyAll`, если более одного потока ожидают - это разбудит их всех. Тем не менее, только один из потоков сможет захватить монитор (т.к. `wait` в `synchronized` блоке).

Ещё одно различие в том, что `wait` вызывается на `Object`, в то время как  `sleep` вызывается на `Thread`.

Если суммировать, то используйте `sleep()` для time-syncronization и `wait()` для multi-thread-synchronization.

Comment: wait уступает монитор, что позволяет двум и более потокам "быть" внутри synchonized по одному монитору.